# How do you save a file to a directory given by an input type="text" with php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a html page with jQuery and I used ajax to send data to the a php file to save the data.
I have seen other questions like this but none of them seemed to match my purpose.

The data is an iframe's srcdoc.

My html looks like this:

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<h1>hello</h1>" id="iframe"></iframe>
<br />
<input type="text" placeholder="Filename to save as..." id="fn">
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="saveDoc(document.querySelector('#fn').value)">
```

My jQuery and JS looks like this:

```
function saveDoc(e) {
  let iframe = document.querySelector("#iframe");
  let data = {"srcdoc": iframe.srcdoc, "lnk": e};

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saver.php",
    dataType : "text",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 3000,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("SUCCESS");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
  });
}
```

And my php code looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["lnk"]) && isset($_POST["srcdoc"])) {
    $myfile = fopen($_POST["link"], "w");
    fwrite($myfile, $_POST["srcdoc"]);
    fclose($myfile);
    echo $_POST["lnk"];
    echo "\n <br/>";
    echo $_POST["srcdoc"];
  } else {
    echo "Error";
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it, I get an alert message saying "SUCCESS". And the console.log gives me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
Error</body>
</html>
```

What is happening here, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well first of all, `lnk` and `link` are two different things …

Comment: (How dangerous this is, without applying any additional checks, is clear to you, I hope? This could currently be used to overwrite any existing file that your PHP has write access to.)

Comment: `"lnk": e` – what do you think you are actually passing as `e` here? Your function call did not specify any parameter.

Comment: I am only using this myself so I wouldn't be so worried.

Comment: @misorude `function saveDoc(e)`, first line.

Comment: This is the function call, `onclick="saveDoc()"` (implicitly), and you are not passing in any value there.

Comment: Oh, right. I actually did put it but I forgot to put it in the example. Edited.

Comment: `contentType: "application/json"` - you are explicitly sending this to the server as JSON - so you can not access it via `$_POST`. Either remove that contentType, so that it can fall back to the normal way of sending form data, or go inform yourself how to actually read POSTed JSON data in PHP.

Comment: @misorude Thanks, that did it. If you posted that as an answer you'd get 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> contentType: "application/json"
> ```

You are explicitly sending this to the server as JSON - so you can not access it via $_POST. (PHP only populates $_POST for Content-Types `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.)

Either remove `contentType`, so that it can fall back to the normal way of sending form data, or go read up on how to actually read POSTed JSON data in PHP. (That would involve reading the data from `php://input` first, see [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php))

Comment: The data isn't being encoded as JSON, so using the `php://input` for reason JSON wouldn't work without additional client-side work.

Comment: Didn't expect you to actually do it.

Comment: @Quentin that is correct, of course, the data is not actually send as JSON, and jQuery doesn’t automatically encode it as such, based on the contentType. If this should actually send JSON and be processed on the server side as such, a `JSON.stringify` would still be necessary.